# Отправка смс в определенное время

Tags: android

Мне нужно написать приложение, которое в определенное время отправляет смс (текст смс и номер телефона меняются). Допустим, пользователь задал кому что отправить и в какое время. 
Как мне реализовать отправку в определенное время? Что для этого использовать?
Как просто отправить смс на какой-то номер, я разобралась, загвоздка в том, что это нужно выполнить в определенное время.
Читаю про Service, BroadcastReceiver и AlarmManager, но не знаю в каком направлении двигаться, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Читаю про AlarmManager, но совместно с чем его использовать пока не могу разобраться.

Comment: [Calendar][1] ?


  [1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: Ну понятно, что нужно использовать календарь для установления времени отправки. Но проблема не в этом.

Comment: Пока реализован пользовательский интерфейс - добавление в БД данных об отправке: сообщение, номер для отправки и время, в которое должно отправиться. Как выполнять отправку по времени не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `AlarmManager#setRepeatingAlarm`.

Так же может сработать способ с Service и `Handler#postAtTime`.

Для оперирования временем — используйте `Calendar`.